# SVN and GIT commit history & code differences

Tags: svn, git-merge, git-commit, git-push, svncommit

Where are the log messages , commit history and code differences are stored in SVN & GIT. How are they different in terms of maintaining commit history and code differences?

Comment: get a view on commit history in logcat window.

Answer (score 0):

The commit history are in `svn log` and `git log`. The code differences are `svn diff` and `git diff` respectively; (as you can see there are a lot of similarities between the two already ;) ).

The difference between how they maintain commit history/code differences is very *very* minute. Once you commit a change to the repository (with either VCS), they don't go away. Those changes are always in the repository in whatever branch you commit them in. The differences between `git` and `svn` comes from the other various features of the two systems (such as re-basing in `git` or using `svn externals` in `svn`, as an example).

Now, viewing diffs via the command line can be rather.. Verbose to some extent (read: ugly). I would recommend something like git-extensions or TortoiseSVN for viewing diffs as you will have a much cleaner (and easier to use) interface for seeing the differences between two versions.